# CSS Grid Row Height

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid that is being populated by an API in a loop. I have 4 rows of 5 elements. I have been able to get the column widths correct but am struggling with adjusting individual column heights.

I would like the 3rd element of each row to take up 2 rows in height and all others to take up only one.

Here is what I have for HTML/CSS so far:

```css
.feedContain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(auto, 1fr)) minmax(auto, 2fr) repeat(2, minmax(auto, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.feedContain .news-item {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedContain">
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
</div>
```

All elements have the class of .news-item.

There should be 4 rows but the center elements (there should only be 2) should span 2 rows each.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please update your post with relevant HTML code so that we may more easily assist you.

Comment: Done. Basically a grid of 18 items. Counting from the left of each row the 3rd item should be 2 rows tall (essentially only 2 items in this column) and then 2 - 1 row columns to the left and right of them.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: A functional selector would be: `.news-item:nth-child(5n+3)` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zvp7n4d1/)), unfortunately I can't think of a reliable way to have those elements have double-height (without using `display: flex` and setting the height explicitly, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zvp7n4d1/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems I found the solution on my own. Here was my fix:

```css
.feedContain{
      display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(auto, 1fr)) minmax(auto, 2fr) repeat(2, minmax(auto, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.feedContain .news-item{
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.socialB .feedContain .news-item:nth-child(3), .socialB .feedContain .news-item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.socialB .feedContain .news-item:nth-child(3) {
    grid-row: 1/3;
}

.feedContain .news-item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 3/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedContain">
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
  <div class="news-item"></div>
</div>
```

This seems to be the least insane solution ;)